# more setup or just an incorrect script to make a db create table query

Tags: php, mysql

I installed PHP and Mysql to run on IIS6 (only installed both, and I am unknown about the setup to get them [PHP and MYSQL] to work together) and I use the following code to create a table in EMPLOYEE in the PEOPLE database I issued from mysql client command line.

```
<?php
$username="root@localhost";
$password="password";
$database="people";
mysql_connect(localhost,$username,$password);
@mysql_select_db($database) or die("Unable to select database");
$query="CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEE (id INT(7) NOT NULL 

AUTO_INCREMENT,FirstName VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL, LastName VARCHAR

(15) NOT NULL, PhoneNumbers VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL, MobileNumbers 

VARCHAR(20), Position VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL, PRIMARY  KEY(id))";
mysql_query($query);
mysql_close();
?>
```

Yet, it displays the die message. I search google for the setup of mysql and php but fail to see any corrections of php.ini offered to run the script with the database. Thank you for any help.

EDIT:
Thank you for your concerns, it works after corrected as follows,

```
    <?php
    $username="root";
    $password="password";
    $database="people";
    mysql_connect(localhost,$username,$password);
    @mysql_select_db($database) or die("Unable to select database");
    $query="CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEE (id INT(7) NOT NULL 

    AUTO_INCREMENT,FirstName VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL, LastName VARCHAR

    (15) NOT NULL, PhoneNumbers VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL, MobileNumbers 

    VARCHAR(20), Position VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL, PRIMARY  KEY(id))";
    mysql_query($query);
    mysql_close();
    ?>
```

Comment: If you're new to mySQL, I would recommend you download and install MySQL Workbench (free). It makes database management and troubleshooting a breeze.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of just saying there's a problem, have it tell you what the problem is:

```
@mysql_select_db($database) or die("Unable to select database: " . mysql_error());
```

For debugging/developing, you should have an `or die(mysql_error())` after EVERY `mysql_*()` function call.

The problem is this:

```
mysql_connect(localhost,$username,$password);
              ^^^^^^^^^
```

That's an unquoted string, which'll be interpreted as an undefined constant by PHP, evaluating to a null string - so you're trying to connection to... "nothing".

Comment: In addition to the answer, try avoiding suppressing errors using the @ sign when possible. It tends to be bad practice. Make sure you do proper error checking/handling instead.